# How to replace the content of multiple tags in html-file? [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates

We have html-file:

```
<div class="my1">MY1</div>
<h1 class="my2">MY2</h1>
<p class="my3">MY3</p>
<div class="my2">MY2</div>
```

and json-file with replace values:

```
{
    "my1":"new my1",
    "my2":"new my2",
    "my3":"new my3"
}
```

In result must be new html-file with new values.

How to do this? Without DOM!

Comment: Did you do some research regarding this problem?

Comment: Of course, but didn't find a simple explanation of what to do.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand why you are against DOM building as it is relativity easy to do. There are lightweight modules such as cheerio that fulfill your requirements and have a simple API (similar to JQuery).

## Fully working example

This example does exactly what you want using the [cheerio node module](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

### Files

**replace.js**

```js
var fs = require('fs')
, cheerio = require('cheerio');

// html file we are working on
var htmlPath = __dirname + '/htmlFile.html';
// html file to output modified html to
var outPath = __dirname + '/htmlFixed.html';

// load in the json file with the replace values
var replaceValues = require('./replaceValues.json');

fs.readFile(htmlPath, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(error, data) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data); // load in the HTML into cheerio

    for (var key in replaceValues) {
        // the keys are class names, use them to pick out what element
        // we are going to modify & then replace the innerHTML content
        // of that element
        $('.' + key).html(replaceValues[key]);
    }

    fs.writeFile(outPath, $.html());
});
```

**htmlFile.html**

```html
<div class="my1">MY1</div>
<h1 class="my2">MY2</h1>
<p class="my3">MY3</p>
<div class="my2">MY2</div>
```

**replaceValues.json**

```js
{
    "my1":"new my1",
    "my2":"new my2",
    "my3":"new my3"
}
```

### Usage

```
node replace.js
```

### Results

After running the script, you will have a new file in the same directory as the original HTML file named `htmlFixed.html` with the changes performed with the contents:

```html
<div class="my1">new my1</div>
<h1 class="my2">new my2</h1>
<p class="my3">new my3</p>
<div class="my2">new my2</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why? This is relatively simple and solves your problem.

Comment: so delivered exercise

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not have any notion of a Document Object Model (i.e. the DOM) -- ["Why doesn't node.js have a native DOM?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6657216/1026459) -- and as such does not have access to a way to instantiate HTML Elements (which would be nice to have access to in order to parse your html).

As a result, you must import a library to use as a parser (just like any other server side implementation must when dealing with html - [don't regex it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1026459)).

The current leader in doing this is **[jsDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)**

Comment: @user3188101 - The word is "parsing". You need to parse the HTML in your text file. In order to parse it, you must load it into a parser. There is no "DOM building" here, it is emulating the DOM in order to parse your text file.

Comment: +1 @TravisJ I must have missed your answer as I was typing mine out yesterday. Would have saved me some time ;-)