# Using Node.js, given some HTML, can a DOM tree be created?

Tags: node.js

Sometimes when doing DOM scripting and experiments, we can use a web page, have some HTML, and do our DOM traversal using JavaScript, and run the code in a browser.

But if we use NodeJS, can we do the same? (The missing part is how to create a DOM tree and be able to do `document.getElementById()` and so forth?)

Comment: related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657216/why-doesnt-node-js-have-a-native-dom?

Answer (score 1):

There are DOM and DOM-like implementations for node.js, including:

- https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dom
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Disclaimer: I haven't ever used any of them.