# Node JS Click Button on Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, button

I'm trying to make a web-scraper in Node JS and I've hit a roadblock.
I need to click on a button BUT, if I'm not mistaken, Node doesn't actually render the web-page like a browser would so I can't use a selector or X-Path.

How then, could I click a specific button with the value "yes" if I can't use the selector or X-path? There's no id unique to only the yes button.

I'm asking this because I want to parse a specific web-page but I get redirected to a page that asks me to press two buttons.
Pressing 'Yes' will bring me to the page I want. Pressing 'No' will obviously stop me from going forward.

Is there any way to do what I want within the confines on Node without having to resort to something like JSDOM?

Here's part of the HTML i'm working with:

```
<div class="buttons">
<button class="c-btn c-btn-primary" type="submit" name="bigbutton" value="no">no thank you</button>
<button class="c-btn c-btn-primary" type="submit" name="bigbutton" value="yes">continue</button>
</div>
```

I tried using something like this:

```
document.getElementByID("selector").click()
```

but was returned with 'ReferenceError: document is not defined'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't node.js have a native DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657216/why-doesnt-node-js-have-a-native-dom)

Comment: You can't really "click" anything when dealing with scraped content on a webserver, maybe you wanted a headless browser or a bot instead

Comment: Is it possible to simply find out the URL of the redirected page beforehand and have Node scrap it directly?

Comment: If I make a request to go to url X it instantly redirects me to page Y, which is what we have here, two buttons. Clicking continue brings me to the page X i wanted to go to. I have a script written for the data parsing when  I actually land on page X but can't seem to get past Y without clicking continue.

Comment: So I figured out I can't even get past the page itself if I disable cookies- Is there a way to add a cookie that works to my node script so that it clears through?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a headless browser like phantom to do the scraping (or at least get you to a point where you can do the scraping)

Comment: Zombie is a great option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [Zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie)? I've used and worked well! This [link](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/getting-started-zombiejs) is very helpful, since clarify quickly how to perform actions.