# How to parse HTML to DOM with Grunt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, gruntjs

I am new to Grunt, trying to find a way to load multiple HTML files and parse them to extract some values.

I tried to use `jQuery.parseHTML`, `HTMLParser` but both are not defined. Is there a way to include jQuery or a lib that can parse HTML?

```
grunt.config.init({
    concat: {
        options: {
            dest: 'tmp',
            templates: ['public/*.html']
        }
    }
});

var recursiveConcat = function(source, result){
    grunt.file.expand(source).forEach(function(file){
        var data = grunt.file.read(file);
        // parse html to dom
        result += data;
    });
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Node is not a browser so it doesn't have `window` or `document`. Even if you load jQuery you'll still not have a DOM parser.

Comment: Related questions: [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7372972), [Why doesn't node.js have a native DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6657216)

Comment: what does this have to do with grunt specifically?

Answer (score 2):

[Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) is a DOM parser that I enjoy using. I haven't tried this, but [grunt-dom-massager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dom-massager) allows you to load Cheerio in your Gruntfile.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like writing your own Grunt Task is pretty straightforward. 
Samples and walkthroughs [here](https://quickleft.com/blog/grunt-js-custom-tasks/) and [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/01/creating-your-first-grunt-plugin/)

then you create a task using [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser) to manage your process.

However unless you are going to re-use this or pair it with some other grunt task (like grunt-watch) you might find it easier to just create a node script using htmlparser