# Canvas Image manipulation in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to replicate some client-side code, using firebase functions. Basically, I am just trying to take a user image, create a circular version of it with a color around it.

Here is the code that I am currently using, which works on the client side of things, but not in Firebase Functions.

```
export async function createCanvasImage(userImage) {
console.log('createCanvasImage started...');

const canvas = new Canvas(60, 60);
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Creates the blue user image.
async function blueCanvas() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  context.strokeStyle = '#488aff';

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(30, 30, 28, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.stroke();

  context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  console.log('Canvas Image loaded!');
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(30, 30, 28, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.clip();
  context.drawImage(userImage, 0, 0, 60, 60);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, 28, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.clip();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(dataURL);
  resolve(dataURL);
  });
```

}

But it is, unfortunately, returning the following error:

> Error creating one of the canvas images... TypeError: Image or Canvas expected

I suspect it's because the image isn't loading properly, but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to load on the server properly.

I was trying to use some code that is provided in the firebase function samples:

```
 return mkdirp(tempLocalDir)
.then(() => {
// Download file from bucket.
return bucket.file(filePath)
.download({ destination: tempLocalFile });
})
.then(() => {
console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
createCanvasImage(tempLocalFile)
.catch(err => {console.log(err); });
})
.catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be missing the DOM, unless you're importing libraries that aren't shown here. This is the same reason Nodejs doesn't have a `window` or `document` object. There is a good Q&A here [Why doesn't node.js have a native DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657216/why-doesnt-node-js-have-a-native-dom?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

There is a node canvas implementation [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) which can include in your package.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't missing the DOM as [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615397/lex) suggested, I found [this](https://github.com/harthur/kittydar/issues/20) and [this](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/338) post where the issue was the node-canvas version.

I only see Canvas in one module but if you were using more, read the explanation below I found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/487):

> I can't find the other issue that discusses this more, but there is no
>   way to fix this in node-canvas itself because it's a limitation of
>   native addons (two different builds of node-canvas don't produce
>   compatible objects). At some level, your JS code needs to make sure
>   that it's using the same node-canvas everywhere. Without knowing
>   anything about your application, this may mean using `npm v3` or later,
>   which has a flat(ter) node_modules directory; ensuring that everything
>   that depends on node-canvas is allowed to use the same version; and/or
>   providing a central wrapper for node-canvas that you require instead
>   of requiring node-canvas directly. The first two should hopefully Just
>   Work and not require code changes, but may be brittle.