# how to use document.getElementById() in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, document, getelementbyid, dom-node

i'm trying to get elements by id from an html file in a js file using nodejs.
I'm getting the error 'document id not defined' because node doesn't provide a document object model by default.

So how can i use **document.getElementById()** in nodejs ?

Thank you !

Comment: node.js programs don't run in a browser. There is no `document` in the first place. Are you asking how to parse an HTML file in node.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to parse files within the same server you should probably use some of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js) options, because nodejs it's just a JavaScript implementation, There is no `window` or `document` object, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657216/why-doesnt-node-js-have-a-native-dom).   But to answer exactly your question:

> how can I use **document.getElementById()** in nodejs ?

You could do it using [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/)

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control
>   headless Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. It can also be
>   configured to use full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.

Here a basic example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();


        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://example.com/some.html', {waitUntil: 'load'});


    const newPage = await page.evaluate(() => {

        return  document.getElementById("idexample").innerHTML;

        });

     console.log(newPage)

  })();
```

Comment: OP wants to parse an HTML file on the server, not some website.

Comment: @ChrisG You could parse the files of the same server, also  the question is: "how to use document.getElementById() in Nodejs" and this is a way to do that.

Comment: The question doesn't mention there's a server running. And it clearly also says `from an html file`, which means this is almost an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and using `document.getElementById()` was already a wrong alley in the first place. On top of that, the question is a clear duplicate, and answered extensively.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, it's probably an XY problem, I've made a clarification in my answer. Either way if somebody find this question googling how to use document.getElementById() in node,  this is one possible correct answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Use JSDOM npm package:

jsdom is a pure-JavaScript implementation of many web standards, notably the WHATWG DOM and HTML Standards, for use with Node.js. In general, the goal of the project is to emulate enough of a subset of a web browser to be useful for testing and scraping real-world web applications.
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom