# How do you check the amount of options in a selector class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I need to write a function to check the number of options in a selector tag using javascript. The only thing is I cannot use jQuery (My script is based on puppeteer and web scraping). If you have any suggestions please leave them down below.
Example:

[image]

I need the function to return 2 in this example.

Thanks.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('select#size > option').length` but it is better to use the form id element

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the following code snippet:

```
var x = document.getElementById("size").length;
```

x will hold the number of options here.

source: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_select_length.asp

Comment: This is because you are using puppeteer in node.js , the code given is the equivalent in scripted javascript
To see how you would use a similar function(not the exact same as the one you require) in puppeteer see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52256799/how-to-use-document-getelementbyid-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children` property to extract option from `select`

`document.getElementById('size').children` you will get HTMLCollection which consists of all the option present inside that `select`

To get the count
`document.getElementById('size').children.length`

You cannot iterate over HTMLCollection to perform an action 
You need to convert the HTMLCollection to Array in order to perform an action 
`Array.from(document.getElementById('cars').children)`

Comment: @ZachC have you fixed the document error ? from the link provided by Mamun

Comment: yes I will look into it after I have finished my school work

Comment: @ZachC ok do let me know if you still got any issue