# How to use jquery in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

How to use jquery in node js. Please Help me 
I'm using this code

```
 const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>');
const $ = require('jquery')(window);
var connection = require('./database');
connection.query(
 "SELECT * FROM cr_state",
  function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    $('#state').html('<option value="1">test</option>')
  }
);
```

But this code is  not working.How to use jquery?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Presumably your querying your database on the server *which has no access to the DOM* of the client?!

Comment: @Li357 how to use dropdwon in node js

Comment: @Li357 state list are showing in console but jquery html is not working .

Comment: You can check out my previous answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js/54372826#54372826 import $ from 'jquery'; window.jQuery = window.$ = $; That's all you need .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use jQuery with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

By Default Nodejs is not designed to read DOM

```
$('#state').html(html); // jquery virtual DOM
```

if you wanna read DOM using node then you have to install DOM parser.

For more info: [Why doesn't Node.js have a native DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657216/why-doesnt-node-js-have-a-native-dom)

and to install DOM parser: [How do I parse a HTML page with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372972/how-do-i-parse-a-html-page-with-node-js)

Comment: I'm using this code for read DOM
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);